# Erro android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException

Tags: java, android

Esse metodo da minha activity:

```
private void loginEmailSenha() {

        editTextEmailLogin.setError(null);
        editTextSenhaLogin.setError(null);

        controllerUsuario = new ControllerUsuario(this);
        String email = editTextEmailLogin.getText().toString();
        String senha = editTextSenhaLogin.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            editTextEmailLogin.setError(getString(R.string.error_field));
            focusView = editTextEmailLogin;
            cancel = true;

        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(senha)) {
            editTextSenhaLogin.setError(getString(R.string.error_field));
            focusView = editTextSenhaLogin;
            cancel = true;

        }

        if (cancel) {
            focusView.requestFocus();

        } else {

            controllerUsuario.buscarEmailSenha(email, senha);

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OptionsUserActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            limparCampos();

        }
    }
```

metodo do controller:

```
public User buscarEmailSenha(String email, String senha) {
        return ir.buscarEmailSenha(email, senha);
    }
```

metodo do meu repository:

```
@Override

public User buscarEmailSenha(String email, String senha) {

User user = null;

        Cursor cursor = abrirBanco().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SqliteHelper.NOME_TABELA + " WHERE " +
            sqliteHelper.EMAIL + " = '" + email + "' AND " + sqliteHelper.SENHA + " = '" + senha + "'", new String[]{email, senha} );

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            user = new User();
            user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
            user.setSenha(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("senha")));
        }

        return user;
```

Está gerando o seguinte erro:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@fteste": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email =
>   teste@fteste.com AND senha = teste123.

Class SqliHelper

```
 public static final String NOME_TABELA = "usuario";
 public static final String NOME = "nome";
 public static final String EMAIL = "email";   
 public static final String TELEFONE = "telefone";   
 public static final String SENHA = "senha";
 public static final String COLUNA_ID = "_id";

 public static final String TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE " + NOME_TABELA "( "

 COLUNA_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "            
 NOME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"            
 EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL,"            
 TELEFONE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"            
 SENHA + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

 @Override

 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

       db.execSQL(TABLE_USER);        
       db.execSQL(TABLE_CARONA);

  }
```

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, fornecendo detalhes do problema, apenas colando o codigo fica dificil a analise e, consequentemente, te ajudar a resolver. Aproveite e leia [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se vc adicionar os parametros no SQL (`sqliteHelper.EMAIL + " = '" + email +` ), não há a necessiade do segundo parametro no `rawQuery`.

Exemplo:

```
Cursor cursor = abrirBanco().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SqliteHelper.NOME_TABELA + " WHERE " +
            sqliteHelper.EMAIL + " = '" + email + "' AND " + sqliteHelper.SENHA + " = '" + senha + "'", null );
```

ou

```
         Cursor cursor = abrirBanco().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SqliteHelper.NOME_TABELA + " WHERE " +
                sqliteHelper.EMAIL = ? AND " + sqliteHelper.SENHA + " = ?", new String[]{email, senha} );
```

A quantidade de parâmetros do Array deve ser igual a quantidade de `'?'` no sql.

Espero ter ajudado!

Saudações

Obs.:

Para que ele passe a próxima tela apenas se houver usuário na banco, tente isso:

```
  if (cancel) {
        focusView.requestFocus();

    } else {

         User user = controllerUsuario.buscarEmailSenha(email, senha);

       if(null != user){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),         OptionsUserActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);

        }else{
          // Nao existe usuario com este login e senha
        }

    }
```

Comment: não consegui resolver problema, obg por ajudar! Ele não dar erro algum, caso coloque email e senha não cadastrados aceita.

Comment: Não conseguiu? o Que acontece? consegue debugar? Sabe se entra no if? Estamos aqui para te ajuda amigo!

Comment: Todos os métodos começando activity passando controller, chegando repository.

Comment: Acho q entendi o q VC quer dizer.... Lá na sua Activity VC deve receber o User e verificar se ele é null.... Ou melhor se ele não é null. Para depois invocar a outra Activity... Veja onde VC chama o método buscarEmailSenha()... Independente do que retorna no seu controller, ele sempre vai chamar a OptionsUserActivity.

Comment: Não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: adiconei o exemplo de como validar o Usuario na resposta ! Analise e em caso de duvida, poste para podermos ajudar!

Comment: gerou seguinte erro android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: tente assim: **"SELECT  "SqliteHelper.EMAIL+" , "+SqliteHelper.SENHA+" FROM "**

Comment: já tentei assim não deu certo.

Comment: mostre onde vc cria a tabela

Comment: editei pergunta

Comment: Por acaso vc usa o NOME_TABELA para criar a tabela carona?

Comment: isso mesmo ....

Comment: Entao ele deve estar sobre escrevendo a tabela Usuario. Tente criar com nomes difrentes a tabela

Comment: Irei tentar aqui.

Comment: não deu certo, continuo com mesmo problema. Pensei em WebService